# My code for changing the value of a float variable doesnt work

Tags: c, floating-point

Please explain why this doesnt work, I'm new to this.

```
float x = 1;
float y = 4.5578;
while (x >= 1)
{
    x = y - 1.0;
}
printf("%f", x);
```

I know you can fix the code like this

```
float y = 4.5578;
float x = 0;
while (x >= 0)
{
    x--;
}
printf("%f", x);
```

but i want to know why the previous doesnt work

Comment: In the first code, you never change `y`, so the same value of `x` is calculated each time, so the loop condition is always true, so the program doesn't terminate.  But you should have explained what you see.  The second program only iterates once.  You should learn how to use a debugger, or how to add print statements to the code to track what goes on.

Comment: `x = y - 1.0;` That is setting the same value every iteration. That is, `x` is always 3.5578 which will never satisfy the exit condition. That's something you should be able to easily see for yourself with any basic debugging - run in a debugger or even basic debug print statements.

Comment: chloew3012, The first loop does change the value from 1.0 to 3.5578. Why do you think the value does not change?

Comment: A tip for those who don't like bugs is to never mix integer constants `1` type `int`, with float constants `1.0f` type `float`, with double constants `1.0` type `double` in the same expression.

Answer (score 2):

In your first snippet, there is no change in the loop - as in, you are changing `x`  to be `y - 1` each time and `y` does not change - goes into infinite loop!

In the second version, `x` does actually change and stop the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
float x = 1;
float y = 4.5578;
while (x >= 1)
{
    x = y - 1.0;
}
printf("%f", x);
```

This code has a value below when it started.

> x = 1
> y = 4.5578

and, the while will end when the x value is lower than 1.

At the first loop, x will be changed.

> x = 3.5578
> y = 4.5578

So, x was changed, but y wasn't changed.
next loop, also x will be '4.5578 - 1.0' and its value is '3.5578'.

That's the problem. This loop will be ended when the x value will be decreased under 1.0.
But, this loop doesn't change the y value, so the x value also didn't change whatever your loop.

The loop will be endless, and this is the error.

if you want to do this code, you have to do it like this.

```
float x = 1;
float y = 4.5578;

float times = 1.0;
while (x >= 1)
{
    x = y - times;
    times += 1.0;
}
printf("%f", x);
```

This will be increased 'times' when the loop is finished, so seconded loop, the value of the x and y will be changed like below.

first loop

> x = 3.5578
> y = 4.5578
> times = 1.0 (when loop ends, times will be increased to 2.0. this value is only when you calculate x and y.)

second loop

> x = 2.5578
> y = 4.5578
> times = 2.0

third loop

> x = 1.5578
> y = 4.5578
> times = 3.0

forth loop

> x = 0.5578
> y = 4.5578
> times = 4.0

Then, boom!
The x's value will be decreased under 1.0, so while loop will be ended. and

```
printf("%f", x);
```

will be showing `0.5578` when loop will be end.

The times' value will be '5.0' when this code ended, but that's not an error or something. This code will be increased 'times' when `x = y - times` calculate will end, so it gets increased that doesn't care about while loop will end.

If you want to end with a 'times' value is '4.0', you have to write code like the below.

```
float x = 1;
float y = 4.5578;

float times = 0.0;
while (x >= 1)
{
    times += 1.0;
    x = y - times;

}
printf("%f", x);
```